# How do I bring other variables along with the render?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'll do my best to phrase this question correctly!

I'm trying to make three different forms on one page. The problem I have is when I do "render "dashboard/index"" it crashes because the other forms are missing their other instance variables (e.g. @check = nil)

If I change it to  "redirect_to dashboard_path", it works fine when submitting correct information or if the validations fails but it will lose all the other information in the form after the redirect.

How do I bring other variables along with the render?
or is my implementation not following good practices?  Is there a better way to structure this?

Or am I just not asking the right questions?

This is not exactly the same code, I tried to remove all unrelated content

in dashboard_controller.rb

```rb
def index

    @calibration = Calibration.new
    @blank = Blank.new
    @check = Check.new

    @last_calibration = Calibration.where(user_id: current_user.id).order(created_at: :asc).last
    @last_blank = Blank.where(user_id: current_user.id).order(created_at: :asc).last
    @last_check = Check.where(user_id: current_user.id).order(created_at: :asc).last

end
```

in index.html.erb

```rb
<% if @last_calbration&.complete? %>
    <%= render 'calibrations/form' %>
<% end %>

<% if @last_blank&.complete? %>
    <%= render 'blanks/form' %>
<% end %>

<% if @last_check&.complete? %>
    <%= render 'checks/form' %>
<% end %>
```

in blanks_controller.rb (and the other controllers)

```rb
  def create
      @blank = Blank.new(blank_params)
      if @blank.save
        redirect_to dashboard_path
      else
        render "dashboard/index"
      end
  end
```

in _blanks_form.html.erb (and other forms)

```rb
  <%= form_for(@blank) do |f| %>
    ...
  <% end %>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I think I found a solution,  I changed the render to redirect_to and passed the variables that failed.  I don't know if this is a proper implementation but it seems to work.  If there are any better ideas, let me know!

in dashboard_controller.erb  ( I did it for each form, but for only 1 form in this case) ...

```rb
def index
  @blank = Blank.new(blank_params[:blank])
end
...

private 
   def blank_params.permit( { blank: [ :user_id, :field1, :field2] } )
```

and in the blanks_controller.rb(and all the other controllers) ...

```rb
def create

 @blank = Blank.new(blank_params)
 if @blank.save
   redirect_to dashboard_path
 else
   redirect_to dashboard_path( blank: @blank.attributes )
  end

end
```

Answer (score 0):

**Reason:**

The reason of your problem is because when we use `render`, the controller methods are not executed. For example if you render the show template from `index` method then only the template of the show method will be rendered and the actual show method will not be executed.

The reason why it workers with redirect is because `redirect_to` executes the actual controller method.

**Solution:**

What you can do is that, you create a common method which initialize these variables

Something like this:

```
def initialize_variables

    @calibration = Calibration.new
    @blank = Blank.new
    @check = Check.new

    @last_calibration = Calibration.where(user_id: current_user.id).order(created_at: :asc).last
    @last_blank = Blank.where(user_id: current_user.id).order(created_at: :asc).last
    @last_check = Check.where(user_id: current_user.id).order(created_at: :asc).last

end
```

Now you can call this method using [`before_action`](https://apidock.com/rails/v4.0.2/AbstractController/Callbacks/ClassMethods/before_action)

```
before_action :initialize_variables, only: [:index, :create] // <- Here add the methods which require these variables

def index

    @calibration = Calibration.new
    @blank = Blank.new
    @check = Check.new

    @last_calibration = Calibration.where(user_id: current_user.id).order(created_at: :asc).last
    @last_blank = Blank.where(user_id: current_user.id).order(created_at: :asc).last
    @last_check = Check.where(user_id: current_user.id).order(created_at: :asc).last

end
```

Hope it helps...

Comment: Thank you very much!  I don't have a create method in my dashboard, so maybe I need to add it there instead of in the original controller?  I'll experiment with it some more!